# How to read the txt file or get the file path after open App via "open in" list in swift?

Tags: ios

I want to read the **txt** file and get the file path from other app(ex: E-mail)

For Example:
 The user send an E-mail to me , and the attachment is a txt file. I want open the txt file and read it from my app.

I reference the following link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html

My App will show on "Open in..." menu , when I click the txt file(attachment) from the e-mail. And the App will open when I choose it to use my App to open the txt file.

**But how to read the txt file and get the file path after the App open?**

Comment: where have u stored the text file?

Comment: @iAnurag I didn't store the text file not yet. So...Before I read the text file , should I store the file to my App's folder ?

Comment: yes you should store it first in document directory

Comment: @iAnurag How to do ? Thanks.

Comment: google it...u will find it easily

Comment: i know how to copy the file to another file , but I can not get the text file on the e-mail. So I can not copy it to my App's document directory.

Answer (score 0):

that file will be stored in **Inbox** folder in app document directory, You can search the documents directory like this:

```
NSString *searchFilename = @"hello.txt"; // name of the txt file you are searching for

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *inboxFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath: inboxFolderPath];

NSString *documentsSubpath;
while (documentsSubpath = [direnum nextObject])
{
  if (![documentsSubpath.lastPathComponent isEqual:searchFilename]) {
    continue;
  }
  NSLog(@"found %@", documentsSubpath);
}
```

if you don't know the file name,you show the list of file names by adding documentsSubpath.lastPathComponent to Array displaying on tableview

Comment: You means the file is stored in e-mail folder , and I just need to search the file on e-mail via my app ?

But the e-mail is one way to receive the text file , it maybe google driver , dropbox...

So I add my App to the "open in " list when all text be press. So...I need to know how to read or get the text file on my app. Not just search folder for the e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems good, try to look in your `launchOptions` from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in your AppDelegate when opened from another app.

Applications are sandboxed, that means applications can't access to each other *(exception to application that shares the same group)*.

### *But…*

You also want to look at [Apple iOS Application Extension Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Services.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1).

Basically, when you receive an e-mail, longpressing the attachment prompts you an action dialog, where you can share, print and make all kind of actions. You will be able to show your own application in that list with Application Extensions.

You may want to look through the whole **[App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1)**, since it's very complete and precise. Maybe you'll find great and unexpected things.

---

### However,

I recommend you to stay on your own solution. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is used to know when app is launched and ***how*** it is launched (from a notification, etc…).

`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` contains an NSURL object that specifies the file to open.
If the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` key is present, your application must open the file referenced by that key and present its contents immediately.
You should probably do it like this:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *fileURL = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileURL
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                               error:&error];
```

I found everything [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1).

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I know the applications are sandboxed , so...should I save the attachment to my applications first ? How to read or get the text file if  I use `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ?